# Swift Google Maps - Load locale tiles

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I am using Swift and Google Maps and have saved some tiles for overlaying in a zoom/lat/lng.png structure at my document directory (like file:///....documents/3/2/3.png)

```
 let urls: GMSTileURLConstructor = {(x, y, zoom) in
        let url = "\(documentsUrl)\(zoom)/\(x)/\(y).png"
        return URL(string: url)
 }
 layer = GMSURLTileLayer(urlConstructor: urls)
 ...
```

The snippet is working for online layers without problems. But when documentsUrl is my local directory, I receive

> Task .<1> load failed with error Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on
>   this server." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was
>   not found on this server.,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///.........../Documents/7/65/42.png

Is there any chance getting offline tiles working with Swift + Google Maps?

Thanks a lot
Karsti

Answer (score 0):

Just use your own class and override the tileFor-function

```
class OfflineTileLayer: GMSSyncTileLayer {
    override func tileFor(x: UInt, y: UInt, zoom: UInt) -> UIImage? {

        let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        let reqPath = URL(string: "\(documentsUrl)\(zoom)/\(x)/\(y).png")!.path
        print (reqPath)
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: reqPath) {
            print ("> IS ACTIVE!")
            let url = NSURL(string: reqPath)
            let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)
            return UIImage(data: data! as Data)
        }

        return kGMSTileLayerNoTile
    }
}
```

and call it from your map init function with

```
 offlineLayer = OfflineTileLayer()
 offlineLayer.map = yourGoogleMap
```